# Cannot install UWP app package in release mode on windows 10 iot core

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have an application that i want publish it using application packages file and install manually i don`t want to use Microsoft Store for publishing my app. I create my application package files as you can see below

[image]

After that when I want to install my application package from Windows 10 iot Device Portal I didn`t got any error but when application run it stucks on splash screen page.

Comment: So it installs, but doesn't run correctly.  Have you tried deploying from Visual Studio in Debug mode?

Comment: Which device did you test on? Is it raspberry pi 3b?@Parsa Karami.

Comment: @Naikrovek yes, when I deploy it in debug mode it works correctly.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Yes, I run it on build 16299 and my device is Raspberry PI 3 model B

Comment: @ParsaKarami, when you deployed it in debug mode with visual studio, have you checked the `Compile with .Net Native tool chain`? I think there is some interop marshaling code in the splash screen page.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you encountered an app hung up when running, you can follow the below steps to troubleshoot.

1. Try to deploy/debug the app from Visual Studio;
2. Try to deploy/debug with a blank app;
3. Set break points or trace the event log to check if there is some exception or what code causes the hung up.
4. When debugging with Visual Studio, checked the `Compile with .Net Native tool chain` in Debug setting, by default, when the app runs in debug mode, it will not use `Compile with .Net Native tool chain`. Please see this [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/).

If possible, you can share the code of your splash page.